# No feedback in Transformers

Tags: transformer

Newbie question about transformers.

I am referring to the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf .

Figure 1 (bottom-right) says: "Outputs (shifted right)".
To me, during generation (not training),
the n-th output of the network seems to be computed by consuming the n-1-th output,
and possibly earlier output entries as well.
Is my understanding correct?

If this is the case, that would be a feedback, no?
But then why transformers are said to be feed-forward?
Is it because the output is "read-only" during training?
Is it correct to say that transformers have feedback at generation time?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct:

- During training, the gold tokens are used as input to the decoder, not the predictions; that's why "there is no feedback". This is called "teacher forcing" and it is the usual approach to train sequence prediction models, also for LSTMs and other RNNs.
- During inference (text generation), the previous token predictions are fed to the decoder as input. Therefore, there is feedback. To predict the first token, the input is a special token indicating the beginning of sequence (bos).

Comment: @diegor please consider either marking the answer as correct or letting me know why you think it's not correct, so that I can improve it.